# High Side P-MOSFET Load Voltage

Tags: mosfet, pmos

I ran into a problem during a circuit simulation. The circuit is rather simple: one P-MOSFET with a load. The MOSFET is acting like a high-side switch. My load is around 4-5 ohms.

I noticed that the simulator calculated (somehow) a large voltage drop on the MOSFET. Why does this keep happening? I tried other simulators too, but got a same result. Shouldn't all the 12 V be at one side of the load if the MOSFET is fully on (minus minor drop from the MOSFET itself)?

[image].

The MOSFET's characteristics:

[image]

Comment: "open" in electronics means "not connected". I think you mean, "on".

Comment: Please attach the datasheet of the MOSFET that you have used in simulation. Is the waveform that you provided the VDS of the MOSFET? If yes, why is it changing with time?

Comment: Probably the PMOS you have selected can't supply the current needed to drive the load. E.g. 10V over 5 Ohms is 2000 mA. Make a plot of the IV characterisitic of the PMOS to see what it can do.

Comment: Last segment is the VDS voltage others is with others load ressistance value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The transconductance \$g_m\$ is too small at 1.14mA/V to support the load resistance. Calculating:$$(V_{GS}-V_{th})g_m=11.9\text{mA}$$

This is all the current available. So about 35mV across the load. The rest across the FET.

Choose a FET with a higher transconductance.